# Close Operation Java

Tags: java, swing

By using `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);` can hide window. but how could i display another window after that ?

When i click on `close button` in my java swing application,i need to hide that window and display another window in my application. how could i do this?

Comment: But why hide, do you intent to bring this window back again, if not why not dispose it completely and bring a new one forward for the user to see ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw yes. i don't need to bring this window back again with out user request. but after closing this, i need to show the window that i hide before show this window.

Comment: So you mean to say, like I opened the app and I clicked on close, so another window will come in front of me, now if i want to see the previously closed window I can do that too or keep the newly opened window, if I want, or keep both in front of me too at any time !!

Comment: @nIcEcOw Actually, there is a button called `Settings` in my apps main window. when i click on that button main window is hiding and show `Settings` window. When i click on close button in `Settings` window, i need to dispose `Settings` window and show main window again that i previously hide. how ever i did my work with `window listener`.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, though multiple `JFrame`s is really not a good approach, what you should be doing is, wrap your settings window inside `JDialog` and keep the actual `JFrame` as is (mean to say hide it when JDialog is on and bring it back again after disposing JDialog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a [window listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).